# Using Curses for a detailed-app with many features

Tags: java, python, terminal, curses

I need to make a detailed (many features) terminal application for a mainframe server. I have found these so far:

- [JCurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/) Updated recently, however was not updated since 2002. Also not be able to find examples.
- [Charva](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/): Last update 2006, broken in Java 1.6
- [Laterna](http://code.google.com/p/lanterna/): Last Update May 2012, but not stable, changing and some features are broken
- [Urwid](http://excess.org/urwid/examples.html): Seems nice, not sure if best choice.

The language is not imprtant to me, however I want it to be simple. I do not want to re-invent the wheel, I want components like text-box, menus, radio buttons to be easily used. Charva seemed the most detailed one, as it was kinda replacement for most swing components, however it is broken. I am not sure If I am searching with the right terms, I cannot find another frameworks. Are they the only choice? Are there any other better libraries?

The similar interfaces I want to build: [example1](http://yast4debian.alioth.debian.org/nfs-curses.png), [example2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/screenshots/259836.jpg), [example3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/screenshots/259834.jpg), [example4](http://primates.ximian.com/~miguel/pictures/tmp4aa56a5c.tmp.jpg)

Comment: Even though Jcurses is over 15 years old Library,I think you should be able to use it after giving it enough time. It seems simple enough once you get the idea. I built a test project on an Android device, What I managed to do resembles example 2/3 more or less. The screenshot is [Here](https://m.imgur.com/t/android/47rJP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) are the go-to way of achieving what you want. There is even a Python [module implementation](http://docs.python.org/howto/curses.html#curses-howto) of it if you don't like C.